# Multiplying a test function to a function in sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

If $f\in \mathbf{L}_{k}^{p}(\mathbf{R}^n) $ and $\varphi \in \mathscr{D}(\mathbf{R}^n)$, show that $\varphi\cdot f \in \mathbf{L}_{k}^{p}(\mathbf{R}^n)$.

How do you show this? I thought of using young's inequality or something along those lines but not sure on how to get started with it.

Comment: The notation you use is one I haven't seen before. Guessing from the title: is $L_k^p$ the sobolev space of $L^p$ functions with up to order $k$ weak derivatives in $L^p$ (what I'd usually call $W^{k,p}$) or is it something else?

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes, it's $W^{k,p}$.

Comment: Look at the product rule for weak derivatives. Once you know that, the key observation is that $\varphi$ and all of its derivatives are smooth functions of compact support (and in particular are bounded) so that all the products you need are suitably integrable.